# 2003 Ford Ranger 6 cyl. 4.0

Tags: cv-boot, cv-joint

I blew the CV boot on my truck yesterday after having all the hubs, rotors, brakes, and a tune up done.  I do not think it should have happened. I kept telling the shop that the truck was not running right.  How can I get the grease off of everything. I am a 74 year old widow and don't know if it is safe to drive.
Please help. Could it just be the boot or is it the CV; that is what I need to know. I can't go anywhere without a car from where I live.,

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If grease is on the brake rotor, that could be of concern. If it's minimal, spraying it down with brake cleaner (or even carb/throttle body cleaner if that's all you have) would deal with that. Take care to avoid spraying the CV joint, suspension, or any hoses with the cleaner

Answer (score 1):

When there is damage to cv boot there is grease leaking, usually takes a lot of driving without grease to damage the CV. You can drive to some car service they will replace the boot and fill in new grease and your CV will be fine. To make sure your CV gets as less damage as possible try to accelerate smoothly, this will lower the stress of a CV (if it's inner ).

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy answer about getting the grease off of everything - you'll need lots of paper towels or shop rags and degreaser (Simple Green, Purple Power, or one of those citrus cleaners). You can find these at Home Depot or Walmart. You can also use the sprayer at a self-serve carwash. Don't use the brushes on heavy grease out of respect for other people who will be scrubbing their car down after you.